# Excel.js custom function caller cell number format

Tags: excel, office-js, exceljs, custom-functions-excel

I'm trying to number format the caller cell for a custom function, specifically to replace the scientific notation with a numeric format for big numbers and then auto fit the column width.
An idea is to check the cell text for presence of "E", but the issue is that the formatting code seems to run before the result is written to the cell (which kind of makes sense, honestly), so I'm doing a comparison and set the cell format accordingly. Setting the cell format works fine (it doesn't need the result written to the cell), but auto fitting the column width doesn't.

Here is the custom function code:

- getData returns a number (or an error string) from an API call
- formatNumber should set the cell number format and autofit the column width, based on the returned number.

```
    async function Test(symbol, metric, date, invocation) {
      const address = invocation.address;
      return await getData(symbol, metric, date)
        .then(async (result) => {
          if (!isNaN(result) && result > 99999999999) {
            await formatNumber(address);
          }
          return result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error: " + error);
          return error;
        });
    }
```

Here is the formatNumber code.

range.text returns #BUSY, which means the data is still retrieved from the API when the function runs. Due to this, autofitColumns will set the column size based on "#BUSY" string length.

```
    async function formatNumber(address) {
      await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const formats = [["#,##0"]];
        const range = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange(address);
        range.load("text");
        await context.sync();
        console.log("range.text: " + range.text);
        range.load("numberFormat");
        await context.sync();
        range.numberFormat = formats;
        range.format.autofitColumns();
        await context.sync();
      });
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time,
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

The custom functions return value will be set to the cell after the function is returned.

I suggest your add-in register an [**onChanged** event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events) handler on the worksheet, and call format.autofitColumns() to handle the event;